# Constant FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING is deprecated when running codeigniter project using php spark server command

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I had a old project which is created in CodeIgniter 4 and was working in my old system now I have taken the copy of the project and trying to run the same.
But its giving me below error

> CodeIgniter v4.1.4 Command Line Tool - Server Time: 2022-04-13
> 06:16:27 UTC-05:00
>
> [ErrorException]
>
> Constant FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING is deprecated
>
> at SYSTEMPATH\HTTP\CLIRequest.php:175
>
> Backtrace:   1    SYSTEMPATH\HTTP\CLIRequest.php:175
> CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions()->errorHandler(8192, 'Constant FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING is deprecated',
> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\hylasto-api\system\HTTP\CLIRequest.php', 175)
>
> 2    SYSTEMPATH\HTTP\CLIRequest.php:67
> CodeIgniter\HTTP\CLIRequest()->parseCommand()
>
> 3    SYSTEMPATH\Config\Services.php:123
> CodeIgniter\HTTP\CLIRequest()->__construct(Object(Config\App))
>
> 4    SYSTEMPATH\Config\BaseService.php:248
> CodeIgniter\Config\Services::clirequest(Object(Config\App), false)
>
> 5    SYSTEMPATH\Config\BaseService.php:189
> CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService::__callStatic('clirequest', [...])
>
> 6    SYSTEMPATH\Config\Services.php:118
> CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService::getSharedInstance('clirequest', Object(Config\App))
>
> 7    SYSTEMPATH\Config\BaseService.php:248
> CodeIgniter\Config\Services::clirequest(Object(Config\App))
>
> 8    SYSTEMPATH\CodeIgniter.php:527
> CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService::__callStatic('clirequest', [...])
>
> 9    SYSTEMPATH\CodeIgniter.php:292
> CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter()->getRequestObject()
>
> 10    SYSTEMPATH\CLI\Console.php:48
> CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter()->run()
>
> 11    ROOTPATH\spark:63
> CodeIgniter\CLI\Console()->run()

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Probably the PHP versions of two host machines are not same. In the command line, you can check it by typing `php -v`. Happy coding..

Comment: thank for the reply.. i don't have the old system as its dead.. and the new system is running php version 8.1.4

Comment: `Deprecated as of PHP 8.1.0, use htmlspecialchars() instead.`. Either you need to update CI version or you need to downgrade PHP version to lower then 8.1.0 - to PHP 7.4 I presume.